# Scope Resolution Operator in c# to access global variable?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Program in C++

```
int x=100; //Global declaration
main()
{
    int x=200;
    {
        int y;
        y=x;
        cout<<"Inner Block"<<endl;
        cout<<x<<endl;
        cout<<y<<endl
        cout<<::x<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"Outer Block"<<"\n";
    cout<<x<<"\n";
    cout<<::x;
}
```

Output of this program is:
Inner Block
200
200
100
Outer Block
200
100

I want to try similar thing in c# but when I type ::x,i gives me error...
Please help

What I have tried is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CAScopeResolution_Operator
{
    class Program
    {
        static int x = 100;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x = 200;
            {
                int y;
                y = x;
                Console.WriteLine("Inner Block");
                Console.WriteLine(x);
                Console.WriteLine(y);
                Console.WriteLine(Program.x);  
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Outer Block");
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            Console.WriteLine(Program.x);
            Console.ReadLine(); 
        }
    }
}
```

I have declared static x,but I dont think this is the solution to have similar code in c#... Please help

Comment: There is no such thing as global variable in C#. Your `x` in C# code is class level variable.  (called *Field*)

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Despite "not being globals", static member fields are otherwise interchangeable with "globals".

Comment: `Program.x` is effectively the same as `::x` in this case. Okay, it's a bit more wordy, but that's just how it's done in C#. Since C# doesn't support `::x` as syntax (much less to refer to a "global"), the error is hardly surprising.

Comment: Ok..so My c# code is right in this case...I was confused about scope resolution operator in c#..I think Scope resolution is not use to access variable outside the scope in c#...so there is no such thing as global variable in c# as said by  MarcinJuraszek ..Anyways Thanks for correcting me....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `C#` does not deal with *global variables* as `C++` does, the `::` has a different meaning. It is about namespaces here, as you can identify each member by the class it belongs to.
So if you have namespaces and/or types that share an identifier but in different namespace, you can identify them using `::`-operator.

```
using colAlias = System.Collections;
namespace System
{
class TestClass
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Searching the alias:
        colAlias::Hashtable test = new colAlias::Hashtable();

        // Add items to the table.
        test.Add("A", "1");
        test.Add("B", "2");
        test.Add("C", "3");

        foreach (string name in test.Keys)
        {
            // Searching the global namespace:
            global::System.Console.WriteLine(name + " " + test[name]);
        }
    }
}
}
```

generates this

```
A 1
B 2
C 3
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/c3ay4x3d.aspx) for MSDN reference.

Comment: Thanks for your reply the link you have provided is perfect...Now I understood perfectly ...

Comment: You are very welcome! Good luck and always consider MSDN when in doubt.